# How to check if geolocation is enabled on iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, geolocation, uiactivityindicatorview

How to check if localization is enable on iPhone?

I need to check if geolocation is enable in viewDidLoad method.

This is my viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 

[super viewDidLoad];


// 1. Check connection
[self performSelector:@selector(checkConnection)];



// 2. Loader (activity indicator) ...
progressViewController = [[ProgressViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProgressViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:progressViewController.view];



// 3. Active geolocation
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
[self startGps];



// 4. Data tableView
NSMutableArray *arrEvents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[[ListaEventiSingleton sharedListaEventi] setArrEvents:arrEvents];
[arrEvents release];



// 5. remove loader (activity indicator)
[progressViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

}

//delegate localization
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

```
    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0) {

   locality = @"Non riesco a localizzarti..\n Refresha!";
    }
else {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D here =  newLocation.coordinate;
    latitudine = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", here.latitude];
    longitudine = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", here.longitude];

    [self getAddressFromGmaps];

    [self stopGps];
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(stopUpdatingLocalizzazione) object:nil];

}

labelLocality.text = locality;



// 4. Load data for the table view
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadEvents) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
[tableViewEvents reloadData];


// 5. remove activity indicator
[progressViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

}

Comment: That's not localization. That's geolocation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want [`[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html).

Comment: Although, this does not check if it is enabled for just the current application.